# Cannot hear the sound while I'm recording the screen, and a Bluetooth headphone is connected at the same time

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, recording

I'm using [ZDSoft](https://www.zdsoft.com/) as a screen recorder on Windows 10. When I connect my headphones using Bluetooth and start the screen recording simultaneously, the sound kind of gets muted. There's no sound anymore although if I stop recording and open the recorded file, the sound is good and all of it is recorded. So, the problem is that I cannot hear anything during the recording process. Here is my sound setup on the screen recorder application:
[image]

I tried other options for "Source 1" and "Source 2", but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by setting the **"Default playback device" as "Source 1"** and **"Microphone (High Definition Audio Device)" as "Source 2"**. Now I can hear the sound through my Bluetooth device as I'm recording. The only drawback is that I have to rely on the default microphone of the system as the primary microphone since choosing my Bluetooth device as "Source 2" will lead to muting the sound.